# How to export/import orders in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, csv, importexport, migration

I am moving companies website from old installation 1.7.1 to fresh installation of Magento 1.9.3. I have moved now all the Product and Customer data easily - how do I export/import orders?

I have tried several extensions but they take huge amount of time to export/import as I have over 100k orders, so ideally I would need magento friendly way to move them.

Here is a nice extension: [Bulk Import + Export Orders to CSV](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html)

I will update this post when I find something decent for Dataflow profiles.

Comment: I'm waiting for your update :)